# win-acme: How to generate cleaner pfx filename for SmarterMail

Tags: ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I'm using Win-Acme to generate/renew Let's Encrypt SSL Certificates. For my mail server, SmarterMail, I need to be able to specify the path to the pfx file. But all the PFX files have very long GUID like file names along the lines of g2GlhtVmN0qpHkYa5gWJPw-34843af2f5af3c7bb43f953ed0e047055d4dc740-temp.pfx. In doing some research, people were referencing much cleaner and more obvious pfx filename like mail.myserver.com.pfx.

Anyone know how I can have Win-Acme generate a clearer file name like the above? My main concern is I want to make sure the SSL setting for SmarterMail doesn't break when the cert renews but it just seems there must be an easier way to figure out the corresponding pfx file for the certificate.

The Win-Acme settings file (settings.json) has two settings for PFXFile for path and DefaultPassword but setting those didn't seem to have any impact and don't address my need anyway.